# Shipping personal effects from US to India

Tags: relocation, shipping

I am going to be moving from US to India soon and have about 75-100kg of personal household items which I would like to ship over and above what we can carry as our airline baggage allowance.

Most of this weight comes from two complete bicycles, books and papers, and clothes. The weight is large enough that paying for excess baggage seems too expensive. I don't care about shipping speed and I have recipients who can collect it so I can ship it all well before I depart.

What are the best options for this?

Comment: My limited experience (not on this route) is that for small amounts of stuff, excess baggage is often the cheapest way. However, I'm not sure how feasible it is to use excess baggage if you can't carry / push it all.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the US Postal Service doesn’t offer sea mail shipping anymore.

You could try UPS or FedEx but their air rates are rather exorbitant for large international packages and they don’t have sea mail.

You don’t have enough to really justify shipping your own ocean container or even quarter container.

I agree with a commenter that you may find it cheaper to go with excess baggage on your airplane ticket. Or ask a friend who is going to your country to take things with them. Or cheaper to sell the larger items and rebuy them in your home country.